# JLabel,controlled through mosemotionliistner, returned back to original location when another jlabel(not controlled by mouse) enters and leaves JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, mousemotionlistener

I'm making a game similar to feeding frenzy. I'm using `mouseMotionListener` to move a `JLabel` around a `JFrame`. At the same time, there are other `JLabels` that act as other fish to be eaten by the `JLabel` controlled by the mouse. Every time a `JLabel fish` (not controlled by mouse) moves in to and out of the screen, the `JLabel` controlled by the mouse returns back to a standard location on the screen, the center of the top half of the screen. What can I do to stop that from occurring?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class playFishGame extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
   private JFrame board;// the main board
   private JLabel fish;
   private JLabel enemyFishS;
   private JLabel enemyFishS2;
   private JLabel enemyFishS3;
   private ImageIcon fishPic;
   private ImageIcon enemyFishSPic;
   private ImageIcon winBackground;
   private ImageIcon background;
   private ImageIcon loseBackground;
   ImageIcon fishSmall1r = new ImageIcon("data/fishSmall1r.png");
   ImageIcon fishSmall1l = new ImageIcon("data/fishSmall1l.png");
   ImageIcon fishSmall2r = new ImageIcon("data/fishSmall2r.png");
   ImageIcon fishSmall2l = new ImageIcon("data/fishSmall2l.png");
   ImageIcon fishSmall4r = new ImageIcon("data/fishSmall4r.png");
   ImageIcon fishSmall4l = new ImageIcon("data/fishSmall4l.png");
   private fish fishFish;
   private fish enemyFishSFish;
   private fish enemyFishSFish2;
   private fish enemyFishSFish3;
   private int origin;
   private boolean contact, win;
   Cursor blankCursor = null;

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      playFishGame play = new playFishGame();
   }

   public playFishGame() {
      blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("data/blank.png"),
            new Point(0, 0), "blankCursor"); // blank.png is any tranparent
                                             // image.
      board = new JFrame("Play Fish Game");
      board.setSize(1300, 700);
      board.getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);
      board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      board.add(this);// adds JLabel to JFrame
      this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
      board.setVisible(true);
      ImageIcon fishPic = new ImageIcon("data/sfr.gif");
      fish = new JLabel(fishPic);
      enemyFishS = new JLabel(" ");
      enemyFishS2 = new JLabel(" ");
      fishFish = new fish(617, 0);
      enemyFishSFish = new fish(1300, 350);
      enemyFishSFish2 = new fish(0, 500);
      // enemyFishSFish3= new fish(1300,200);
      this.add(fish);
      this.add(enemyFishS);
      this.add(enemyFishS2);
      contact = false;
      win = false;
      repaint();
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            if (enemyFishSFish.initiate == true) {
               randomFishSmall(enemyFishSFish, enemyFishS);// picks image and
                                                           // starting
                                                           // point/side
               enemyFishSFish.initiate = false;
            }
            if (enemyFishSFish.chooseSide == 0) {
               enemyFishSFish.moveLeft();
               if (enemyFishSFish.getX() < 5) {
                  enemyFishSFish.initiate = true;
               }
            } else if (enemyFishSFish.chooseSide == 1) {
               enemyFishSFish.moveRight();
               if (enemyFishSFish.getX() > 1295) {
                  enemyFishSFish.initiate = true;
               }
            }
            if (enemyFishSFish2.initiate == true) {
               randomFishSmall(enemyFishSFish2, enemyFishS2);// picks image and
                                                             // starting
                                                             // point/side
               enemyFishSFish2.initiate = false;
            }
            if (enemyFishSFish2.chooseSide == 0) {
               enemyFishSFish2.moveLeft();
               if (enemyFishSFish2.getX() < 5) {
                  enemyFishSFish2.initiate = true;
               }
            } else if (enemyFishSFish2.chooseSide == 1) {
               enemyFishSFish2.moveRight();
               if (enemyFishSFish2.getX() > 1295) {
                  enemyFishSFish2.initiate = true;
               }
            }
            enemyFishS.setLocation(enemyFishSFish.getX(), enemyFishSFish.getY());
            contact(enemyFishSFish);
            enemyFishS2.setLocation(enemyFishSFish2.getX(),
                  enemyFishSFish2.getY());
            contact(enemyFishSFish2);

            // contact(enemyFishSFish);
            // enemyFishS2.setLocation(enemyFishSFish2.getX(),enemyFishSFish2.getY());
            // enemyFishS3.setLocation(enemyFishSFish3.getX(),enemyFishSFish3.getY());
         }
      }, 0, 100);
      board.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
      board.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
   }

   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
      System.out.println(evt.getPoint().x + ", " + evt.getPoint().y);

      if ((evt.getPoint().x < 1231) && (evt.getPoint().y < 623)) {
         fish.setLocation(evt.getPoint().x, evt.getPoint().y);
         fishFish.override(evt.getPoint().x, evt.getPoint().y);
      }
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            origin = fishFish.getX();
         }
      }, 0, 100);
      int posneg = origin - evt.getPoint().x;
      ImageIcon sfr = new ImageIcon("data/sfr.gif");
      ImageIcon sfl = new ImageIcon("data/sfl.gif");
      ImageIcon mfr = new ImageIcon("data/mfr.gif");
      ImageIcon mfl = new ImageIcon("data/mfl.gif");
      if (posneg < 0) {
         if (fishFish.sFish < 10)
            fish.setIcon(sfr);
         if (fishFish.sFish > 9)
            fish.setIcon(mfr);
      }
      if (posneg > 0) {
         if (fishFish.sFish < 10)
            fish.setIcon(sfl);
         if (fishFish.sFish > 9)
            fish.setIcon(mfl);
      }

   }

   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
   }

   // 95/34
   public void contact(fish enemyFish) {
      if ((Math.abs(fishFish.getX() - enemyFish.getX())) < 48
            && (Math.abs(fishFish.getY() - enemyFish.getY()) < 36)
            && (fishFish.sFish < 10)) {
         fishFish.sFish++;
         enemyFish.initiate = true;
      }
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      background = new ImageIcon("data/background3.png");
      winBackground = new ImageIcon("data/");
      loseBackground = new ImageIcon("data/");
      if ((contact == false) && (win == false))
         g.drawImage(background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
      if (contact == true)
         g.drawImage(loseBackground.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
      if (win == true)
         g.drawImage(winBackground.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
   }

   public void randomFishSmall(fish changeFishFish, JLabel changeFish) {
      int chooseType = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
      // int chooseType=2;
      int chooseSide = (int) (Math.random() * 2);// left=0right=1
      int chooseSpeed = (int) (Math.random() * 12) + 6;
      int choosePlacement = (int) (Math.random() * 1288) + 15;
      changeFishFish.chooseType = chooseType;
      changeFishFish.chooseSide = chooseSide;
      changeFishFish.chooseSpeed = chooseSpeed;
      changeFishFish.choosePlacement = choosePlacement;
      if (chooseType == 0) {
         if (chooseSide == 0) {
            changeFish.setIcon(fishSmall1l);
            changeFishFish.override(1300, choosePlacement);
            // changeFishFish.
         } else {
            changeFish.setIcon(fishSmall1r);
            changeFishFish.override(0, choosePlacement);
         }
         changeFish.setLocation(changeFishFish.getX(), changeFishFish.getY());
      } else if (chooseType == 1) {
         if (chooseSide == 0) {
            changeFish.setIcon(fishSmall2l);
            changeFishFish.override(1300, choosePlacement);
         } else {
            changeFish.setIcon(fishSmall2r);
            changeFishFish.override(0, choosePlacement);
         }
         changeFish.setLocation(changeFishFish.getX(), changeFishFish.getY());
      } else if (chooseType == 2) {
         if (chooseSide == 0) {
            changeFish.setIcon(fishSmall4l);
            changeFishFish.override(1300, choosePlacement);
            // changeFishFish.
         } else {
            changeFish.setIcon(fishSmall4r);
            changeFishFish.override(0, choosePlacement);
         }
         changeFish.setLocation(changeFishFish.getX(), changeFishFish.getY());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to get help, it would be better to post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and there is quite good chance that you will debug your code in a process of creating it. Right now, your code is incomplete to solve your problem, and increadibly hard to read

Comment: Not the cause of your current problem, but a potential source of other problems is that you're using the wrong Timer, the `java.util.Timer`. This timer makes its calls off of the Swing event thread, risking difficult to debug intermittent threading violations. Use a `javax.swing.Timer` or "Swing Timer" instead.

Comment: The description of the problem makes me think this would be much easier using pure custom painting (and not dealing with 'moving labels').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

1. Class names start with an upper case character. Learn by example. Just look at the Java API and you will see all class names start with an upper case character.
2. Don't do I/O in a painting method. Painting methods are called whenever Swing determines a component needs to be repainted. It is not efficient to read files every time. Read the images when the class is created.
3. Don't hardcode the size of the frame - `board.setSize(1300, 700);` Not everybody uses the same resolution. To maximize the frame you can use: `board.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

> returns back to a standard location on the screen, the center of the top half of the screen

By default a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`. When you change the location of the other labels the layout manager is invoked to components a place in the position determined by the layout manager.

If you have random placement of a component because you are using the mouse to drag the component, then you need to use a "null layout" on the panel. When you do this you are now responsible for manually setting the "size and location" of every component you add to the panel.

Comment: Also note use of `java.util.Timer` when he should be using `javax.swing.Timer`. 1+

Comment: I tried `board.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`   but it didn't work. Is that the right code? @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I switched to `javax.swing.Timer` but the problem still persists.